# c++ glade gtk+program right click menu

Tags: c++, gtk, glade

I can not manage my context menu here is my code

```
   #include <gtk/gtk.h>
   int on_Form1_button_press_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer *user_data)    {
  g_print ("Button pressed.\n"); 

   const gint RIGHT_CLICK = 3;

 if (event->type == GDK_BUTTON_PRESS) {

     GdkEventButton *bevent = (GdkEventButton *) event;

     if (bevent->button == RIGHT_CLICK) {

         g_print ("Right Clicked.\n");

         gtk_menu_popup(GTK_MENU(widget), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, bevent->button, bevent->time);

         }

     return TRUE; 

 }

 return FALSE;
   }
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])    {
   GtkBuilder      *builder;
   GtkWidget       *window;
   GtkWidget       *menu1;
   GtkWidget       *item1;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

   builder = gtk_builder_new();

   gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "FormPopup.glade", NULL);
   window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Form1"));
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    menu1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "menu1"));
    item1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "item1"));

    g_signal_connect_swapped (G_OBJECT(window), "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(on_Form1_button_press_event), menu1);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(item1), "activate", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

   g_object_unref(builder);

   gtk_widget_show_all(window);

   gtk_main();

   return 0;    }
```

Glade file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!-- Generated with glade 3.22.0 -->
 <interface>
 <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
 <object class="GtkWindow" id="Form1">
   <property name="can_focus">False</property>
   <signal name="button-press-event" handler="on_Form1_button_press_event" swapped="no"/>
   <child>
     <placeholder/>
   </child>
   <child type="titlebar">
     <placeholder/>
   </child>
 </object>
 <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu1">
   <property name="visible">True</property>
   <property name="can_focus">False</property>
   <child>
     <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="item1">
       <property name="visible">True</property>
       <property name="can_focus">False</property>
       <property name="label" translatable="yes">quit</property>
       <property name="use_underline">True</property>
       <signal name="activate" handler="on_item1_activate" swapped="no"/>
     </object>
   </child>
 </object>
</interface>
```

error message:

```
   GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 17:58:37.126: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkMenu'
   Gtk-CRITICAL **: 17:58:37.127: gtk_menu_popup: assertion 'GTK_IS_MENU (menu)' failed
```

thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want to augment your chance to have feedback, you should be more specific to describe your problem. SO is not a debugging site, thus please precise what you tried, etc.

Comment: I don't know GTK, but wouldn't `widget` be the widget that was clicked (ie the window or the widget underneath it) rather than the menu? I think you meant `GTK_MENU(menu1)`. (after making that pointer accessible to your callback, of course)